# Unable to start embedded container nested exception and Hibernate classNotFound exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to run a simple Spring boot application by following a Youtube tutorial. But I keep getting these errors.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
2016-07-29 01:00:35.925 ERROR 1488 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.test.ReservationServiceApplication.main(ReservationServiceApplication.java:31) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:195) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1170) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:77) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:67) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:45) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:41) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.<clinit>(HibernatePersistence.java:46) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader$CachingPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:177) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:84) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.getProviders(Persistence.java:69) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.access$000(Persistence.java:23) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:109) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:46) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1612) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1597) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:609) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:580) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:524) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:492) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:407) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:852) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.validate(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:350) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:271) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:241) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

And the Video tutorial I am trying to follow is this : [Bootiful MS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyK5QrKCbwM)

This is my `pom.xml` file

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.cloud.release.version>Brixton.SR2</spring.cloud.release.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.release.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

In the error messages, see errors regarding Hibernate. I haven't specified anything related to hibernate anywhere. So, is there some internal dependency on Hibernate that is causing that error?

My Java class is this :

```
package org.test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReservationServiceApplication {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner (ReservationRepository reservationRepository ) {
        return strings -> {
                Stream.of("Hello","World","Eric","Susie","Maxie")
                .forEach( n -> reservationRepository.save(new Reservation(n)));
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReservationServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RepositoryRestResource
interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation, Long> {
    @RestResource(path = "by-name")
    Collection<Reservation> findByReservationName(@Param("rn") String rn);
}

@Entity
class Reservation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String reservationName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    public Reservation() { // why JPA why?
    }

    public Reservation(String reservationName) {
        this.reservationName = reservationName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getReservationName() {
        return reservationName;
    }
}
```

I have been trying to figure out the cause for these errors but the errors don't make any sense to me and none of the related articles, Stackoverflow posts were of anyhelp.

Answer (score 0):

Think it is related to the Eureka dependency still being in the pom file and not  setting of the application name.

Try removing Eureka and running the app again. You could also add a bootstrap.properties file and specify the app name 
spring.application.name=pallet-service

Comment: I removed eureka from the pom file but its still giving the same error.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop Please can you post your properties file?